# C++ typename of member variable

Tags: c++, variables, member, typename

Is it possible to get typename of a member variable? For example:

```
struct C { int value ; };

typedef typeof(C::value) type; // something like that?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in C++03. C++0x introduces `decltype`:

```
typedef decltype(C::value) type;
```

Some compilers have a `typeof` extension, though:

```
typedef typeof(C::value) type; // gcc
```

If you're okay with Boost, they have a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.typo) for it:

```
typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(C::value) type;
```

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you haven't disable extensions with a switch.

Answer (score 5):

Only if you are fine with processing the type in a function

```
struct C { int value ; };

template<typename T, typename C>
void process(T C::*) {
  /* T is int */
}

int main() {
  process(&C::value); 
}
```

It won't work with reference data members. C++0x will allow `decltype(C::value)` to do that more easily. Not only that, but it allows `decltype(C::value + 5)` and any other fancy expression stuff within the `decltype`. Gcc4.5 already supports it.

Comment: I suppose this is the best time to ask. Do you know why they chose `decltype` over `typeof`? `typeof` is "matches" `sizeof`, `decltype` is ugly, and doesn't read as well! :(

Comment: @GMan - Random guesswork: because many compilers probably use `typeof` as a compiler-specific extension, and introducing it as a keyword would probably break a lot of code, as the standard `typeof` would inevitably be different from the compiler-specific `typeof`.

Comment: @GMan i have the same suspicion as Chris - i think it's largely a compatibility issue. As example, `decltype(C::value)` will be a different type than `decltype((C::value))`. My silly tests indicate that `typeof` on GCC yields `int` in both cases.

Comment: @Chris and litb: Ah, that makes sense. May I ask why those would be different types, and what they are? That's awfully confusing.

Comment: @GMan i agree, the rules *are* confusing, i'm afraid :) If you have a class-member access (ptr->mem or obj.mem) or a id-expression (qualified or unqualified name, like C::value or value) as operand then `decltype` will yield the type of that entity. For example, a reference will yield a reference type. If not this, then if the operand is a function call (possibly parenthesized) or an implicit call to an overloaded operator, then `decltype` will yield the return type of it (so `int const f()` and `decltype(f())` yields `int const`). ...

Comment: Otherwise, you get the type of the expression, but as a reference if the expression is an lvalue. So if the operand is `(C::value)` instead of `C::value` you get `int&`. For the function call example, if the operand is `decltype(0, f())` you get `int` (because non-class-type rvalues are not const-qualified). Hope this clears up the matter.

Comment: Yeesh D: Looks like I've got some reading to do. Thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

May not be exactly what you're looking for, but a possibly better solution in the long run:

```
struct C {
  typedef int type;
  type value;
};

// now we can access the type of C::value as C::type
typedef C::type type;
```

This isn't exactly what you want, but it does allow us to hide the implementation type of `C::value` so that we can later change it, which is what I suspect you're after.

Comment: unfortunately I do not control structure, which come from external library and to not have value_type or equivalent

Comment: is it possible then that it is not supposed to be accessible?

Comment: @stefanB library (cuda) has c interface. I am trying to make it suitable for template code.in principle I can write type traits if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to do with it but you would do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C
{
    typedef int VType;
    VType value;
};

int main()
{
    C::VType a = 3;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```