# Getting the type of a member

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++03

**NOTE**: This question was originally asked way back in 2012. Before the `decltype` specifier was fully implemented by any major compilers. You should not be looking at this code unless you only have access to C++03. All major C++11 compliant compilers now support `decltype`.

Is there an easy way to retrieve the type of a member?
In C++03

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    int         age;
    double      salary;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person>     people; //  get a vector of people.

    std::vector<GET_TYPE_OF(Person::age)>   ages;

    ages.push_back(people[0].age);
    ages.push_back(people[10].age);
    ages.push_back(people[13].age);

}
```

I am actually doing this (ie being slightly lazy):

```
#define BuildType(className, member, type)                                 \
        struct className ## member: TypeBase<className, type>              \
        {                                                                  \
            className ## member()                                          \
                : TypeBase<className, type>(#member, &className::member)   \
            {}                                                             \
        }

BuildType(Person, name,     std::string);
BuildType(Person, age,      int);
BuildType(Person, salary,   double);
typedef boost::mpl::vector<Personname, Personage, Personsalary> FunckyMTPMap;
```

But rather than have to force the user to specify the type of the member I want to the compiler to generate it pragmatically.

```
#define BuildType(className, member)                                                  \
struct className ## member: TypeBase<className, TYPE_OF(className ## member)>         \
{                                                                                     \
   className ## member()                                                              \
      : TypeBase<className, TYPE_OF(className ## member)>(#member, &className::member)\
   {}                                                                                 \
}
BuildType(Person, name);
BuildType(Person, age);
BuildType(Person, salary);
typedef boost::mpl::vector<Personname, Personage, Personsalary> FunckyMTPMap;
```

Comment: I don't think C++ lets you even talk about `Person::age` without having an instance of `Person`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: If that's true (and I think it may be), it's somewhat annoying.  How does one discover the sizeof `Person::age`?

Comment: what about creating something like a `typedef int Person::age_t;`?

Comment: sizeof without an instance. Try: `sizeof(reinterpret_cast<Person*>(0) -> age)` Have I misunderstood the question, @SethCarnegie ?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I thought of that today too when I used `offsetof`. Prefer MSN's answer though, because the `offsetof` way has undefined behaviour

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
template <class T, class M> M get_member_type(M T:: *);

#define GET_TYPE_OF(mem) decltype(get_member_type(mem))
```

Is the C++11 way. It requires you to use `&Person::age` instead of `Person::age`, although you could easily adjust the macro to make the ampersand implicit.

Comment: Wow, it works... but I don't get it. How is `&Person::age` turned into the type of `age`, but applying `&Person::age` onto `M T:: *`? What does `M T:: *` even mean or represent?

Comment: See also [C++ typename of member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474401/94687), which suggests for C++11 the use of `decltype` as simple as `decltype(Person::age)`.

Comment: This doesn't work when the member is a C-style array. I propose the following fix:

`template<class T, class M> M* get_member_type(M T:: *);

#define GET_TYPE_OF(mem) ::std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(get_member_type(mem))>`

Comment: @beerboy's solution works for C-style arrays indeed. https://godbolt.org/z/vnbf9qfvh

Answer (score 6):

In C++2003 it can't be done directly but you can delegate to a function template which deduces the type:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
void deduce_member_type(T S::* member) {
     ...
}

int main() {
    deduce_member_type(&Person::age);
}
```

Comment: Same question here, as for the accepted answer: What kind of declaration is `T S::* member`? I don't get it, how `&Person::age` gets applied to `T S::* member`.

Comment: @j00hi: it is a _pointer-to-member_ (variable). The type is composed of the type containing the member and the member type. The normal use of pointer-to-members is with the `.*` or `->*` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your examples you use boost I'd use TYPEOF from boost.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof.html

it works very similarly to decltype of C++11.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference
in your case:

```
std::vector<BOOST_TYPEOF(Person::age) > ages;
```

you can compare the types decltype or BOOST_TYPEOF gives you with typeinfo

```
#include <typeinfo>
cout << typeid(obj).name() << endl;
```

you need to make a proper people vector with length >14 for the example to work.

gcc has typeof or **typeof** doing the same thing.

As a side note. For the example you gave you could just define the types in the struct instead if none of the above is relevant for you.

```
struct Person
{
  typedef  int agetype;
  std::string name;
  agetype         age;
  int         salary;
};
```

then use
    std::vector< Person::agetype > ages;