# Using the type of a class member of the first type in a template

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

Searching the site I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866194/getting-the-type-of-a-member) for getting a type of a member inside a class.
Based on that I made the following example which compiles succesfully.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class sig_class_t{
public:
    int field;
};

class usig_class_t{
public:
    unsigned int field;
};

template <class T, class M> M get_member_type(M T:: *);

template<typename my_class = sig_class_t, typename my_type = decltype(get_member_type(&my_class::field))>
class Tricky{
    my_type it;
public:
    my_type get_it();
    void set_it(my_type value);
};

template<typename my_class, typename my_type>
my_type Tricky<my_class,my_type>::get_it(){
    return it;
}

template<typename my_class, typename my_type>
void Tricky<my_class,my_type>::set_it(my_type value){
    it = value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

How does `get_member_type` is able to decide the type of the given pointer?
This code seems a quite complex, and I would not be comfortable using it if I don't understand how it works.

Comment: An alternative could be `decltype(std::declval<my_class>().field)` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
template<typename my_class = sig_class_t, 
         typename my_type = decltype(get_member_type(&my_class::field))>
class Tricky{
    my_type it;
public:
    my_type get_it();
    void set_it(my_type value);
};
```

You pass `&my_class::field` to `get_member_type`.  `&my_class::field` is a pointer to the `field` member of `myclass` so it has type

```
decltype(my_class::field) myclass::*
```

or to put in it english, a `myclass` member pointer to the type of the `field` member.  By default (since it uses `sig_class_t`) that is

```
int sig_class_t::*
```

Why you pass that to

```cpp
template <class T, class M> M get_member_type(M T:: *);
```

`M` gets deduced as `int` and `T` gets deduced to `sig_class_t`.  The function then "returns" an object of type `M`, so `decltype(get_member_type(&my_class::field))` resolves to `M` (`int` in the default case) and that is how `my_type` gets deduced to being the type that the pointer points to.

Comment: phew.. it's not easy to wrap your head around it.. Almost got it, but how does the `get_member_type` token just disappear?

Comment: @DavidTóth because of `decltype`.  `get_member_type` is what is called a meta function.  That is a function that takes a thing(s) and return something, and you use that return type in a template context.  In this case `decltype` doesn't actually call the function but looks at what type it would return if it had, and returns that type.

Comment: Okay, this clicked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, I find this expression easier to understand:

`decltype(std::declval<my_class>().field)`

The `std::declval<my_class>()` part returns a "dummy" `my_class` object, so we can use `.field` on it. And this subexpression is wrapped in `decltype`, which will give `field`'s type.

(Note, that `declval` can only be used in an unevaluated context. `decltype`'s parameter is such a context.)